# What's the difference of keyboard Single Byte Character Code and keyboard Double Byte Character Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jquery code:

```
$.ui.keyCode.COMMA
```

only can Capture Single Byte Character input,How can Capture Double Byte Character also.
who can help me ? thanks

Comment: That code does not capture any characters.

Comment: @SLaks, It is fair to assume it contains the `e.which` value when western comma (`"\x2c"`) is pressed in a keyup/keydown event. So you can do `if(e.which === $.ui.keyCode.COMMA )` instead of using magic numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"，".charCodeAt(0)` gives me 65292 so you could try

```
$.ui.keyCode.DOUBLE_BYTE_COMMA = 65292;
```

To capture that.

In case that is wrong, you can get the correct number like so:

```
jQuery( document ).bind("keyup", function(e){
console.log(e.which);
});
```

Then hit the chinese comma character in your keyboard and see what number comes up. The number will be shown in your web developer console of firefox/google chrome. Or just do:

```
jQuery( document ).bind("keyup", function(e){
alert(e.which);
});
```

Comment: thanks,i found that in the keydown event,Single Byte Character code is 188 and  Double Byte Character code is 239(other DBC same),in the keyup event,Single Byte Character code and  Double Byte Character code all are 188,i change keydown event to keyup event solved it!